# Complex problems after migrating to Linux

Tags: boot

Every time I open Ubuntu, a new boot is created on my computer, and now boot list is more than ten. Meanwhile, I do not use another operating system.

Another problem is that when booting, I must first boot my hard disk once, then select one of those long lists, and then I can log in to Ubuntu.

Comment: re: 2nd paragraph, that's how Linux works, and how it allows you to multi-boot with Windows and other OSes.  It installs GRUB, which acts like a menu for the available OSes.  You pick what you want from the menu and it boots that.  You can set the delay for you to make a selection to a short time.  If you don't pick something within the delay period, GRUB automatically boots the first OS in the list without your taking any action.  re: 1st paragraph, that's totally not normal, and it would be hard for people to figure out what's happening without more information.  (cont'd)

Comment: It sounds like maybe something got corrupted.  Rather than trying to diagnose it, it might be faster to just reinstall Ubuntu.  If it's an older computer, it might be worth checking the SMART stats on the HDD.  It also wouldn't hurt to check for possible corruption on the drive with fsck.  BTW, I'd suggest removing the 2nd paragraph.  Besides the fact that it's normal behavior, questions are meant to focus on a single problem.  The question has attracted a vote to close based on it being too broad (more than one issue).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved . Meanwhile, the problem was that I did not create the EFI System partition.

Comment: Kudos for solving this, and thanks for closing the loop by posting the solution.  In two days you can accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.  That will help others by indicating that the problem is solved and there is a proven solution here.